# Attempted many times to limit selected value to 1 if certain radio button is selected using multiselect bootstrap plugin but no use

Tags: jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-multiselect

I have 5 roles with radio button. So if role roleA,B selected user, it automatically selects all values but if we check roleC, it only allows to select one value.Role D,E could select as many value they want.However, I am having issue with RoleC set-up. So Role C is only allowed to select one value but when I go back to Role E,C, the checkbox would be frozen as it was selected RoleC. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Help!

```
here is the code with jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1ar5g43g/1/
```

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#input-user-market").multiselect('select', String | Array, {
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                nonSelectedText: 'Check an option!'
            });

```
    $('.checks').change(

        function () {


            var radioButton = $('.checks:checked').val();

            if (radioButton == "RoleA" || radioButton == "RoleB") {


                $('#input-user-market').multiselect('refresh', false);
            $('#input-user-market').multiselect('selectAll', false);
            $('#input-user-market').multiselect('updateButtonText', false);

            } else


                if (radioButton == "RoleC") {

                    $("#input-user-market").on("change", function () {
                        var selectedOptions = $('#input-user-market option:selected');

                        if ((selectedOptions.length = 1) && (selectedOptions.length = 1)) {
                            // Disable all other checkboxes.
                            var nonSelectedOptions = $('#input-user-market option').filter(function () {
                                return !$(this).is(':selected');
                            });

                            var dropdown = $('#input-user-market').siblings('.multiselect-container');
                            nonSelectedOptions.each(function () {
                                var input = $('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
                                input.prop('disabled', true);
                                input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
                            });
                        }
                        else if (selectedOptions.length <= 1) {
                            var SelectedOptions = $('#input-user-market option').filter(function () {
                                console.log("1 select")
                                return $(this).is(':selected');
                            });
                            var dropdown = $('#input-user-market').siblings('.multiselect-container');
                            SelectedOptions.each(function () {
                                var input = $('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
                                input.prop('disabled', true);
                                input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            // Enable all checkboxes.
                            var dropdown = $('#input-user-market').siblings('.multiselect-container');
                            $('#input-user-market option').each(function () {
                                var input = $('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
                                input.prop('disabled', false);
                                input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
                            });
                        }
                    });




    }



            else {



                $('#input-user-market option:selected').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('selected', false);
                });
                    $('#input-user-market').multiselect('refresh');




            }
        }


    )




});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ar5g43g/1/

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code as well, that will help us to provide better solution.

Comment: @Shiladitya very shortly!thanks

Comment: @Shiladitya here you go! https://jsfiddle.net/1ar5g43g/1/

Comment: As you can see once I interact with RoleC drop down and then when I try to edit RoleC,D, the checkbox will be disabled except for the one that was selected in RoleC.. I am hitting the wall here :-(((

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1ar5g43g/1/#&togetherjs=x8E5ip6D1S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/1ar5g43g/7/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#input-user-market").multiselect('select', String | Array, {
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    nonSelectedText: 'Check an option!'
 });
  
  var radioButton;

  $('.checks').change(function () {
  radioButton = $('.checks:checked').val();
    $('#input-user-market option:selected').each(function () {
      $(this).prop('selected', false);
    });
    $('#input-user-market').multiselect('refresh');
  
    if (radioButton == "RoleA" || radioButton == "RoleB") {
     $('#input-user-market').multiselect('selectAll', false);
      $('#input-user-market').multiselect('updateButtonText', false);
    }
  });
  
  $("#input-user-market").on("change", function () {
    var selectedOptions = $('#input-user-market option:selected');

    if ( radioButton == "RoleC" && selectedOptions.length === 1) {
        // Disable all other checkboxes.
 
        var nonSelectedOptions = $('#input-user-market option').filter(function () {
            return !$(this).is(':selected');
        });

        var dropdown = $('#input-user-market').siblings('.multiselect-container');
        nonSelectedOptions.each(function () {
            var input = $('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
            input.prop('disabled', true);
            input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
        });
    } else if( radioButton == "RoleC"){
      // Enable all checkboxes.
      var dropdown = $('#input-user-market').siblings('.multiselect-container');
      $('#input-user-market option').each(function () {
          var input = $('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
          input.prop('disabled', false);
          input.parent('li').removeClass('disabled');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="user-form">
  

  
  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input-user-role" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label">Permissions</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                           
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="radio" class="checks "id="A" name="Role" value="RoleA" required data-msg="Please choose one role" />
                                        RoleA
                                    </div>
                                     <div>
                                        <input type="radio" class="checks "id="B" name="Role" value="RoleB" required data-msg="Please choose one role" />
                                        RoleB
                                    </div>
                                     <div>
                                        <input type="radio" class="checks "id="A" name="Role" value="RoleC" required data-msg="Please choose one role" />
                                        RoleC
                                    </div>
                                     <div>
                                        <input type="radio" class="checks "id="A" name="Role" value="RoleD" required data-msg="Please choose one role" />
                                        RoleD
                                    </div>
                                     <div>
                                        <input type="radio" class="checks "id="A" name="Role" value="RoleE" required data-msg="Please choose one role" />
                                        RoleE
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            
                            <label for="Role" class="error block">Please choose one role.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input-user-market" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label">Market</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">



                            <select id="input-user-market" name="MarketIDs[]" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect-selected-text">
                   <option id="select-user-market" value="1">one</option>  
                    <option id="select-user-market" value="2">two</option>   
                     <option id="select-user-market" value="3">three</option>   
                      <option id="select-user-market" value="4">four</option>   
                       <option id="select-user-market" value="5">five</option>   
                                   
                               
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                      </form>
```

I just modified the code a bit.

Comment: thank you! It is so much better than mine. However how to change it in order to allow the user to deselect and select the singular mode as the current one has to deselect the selected in order to tick? How to make it to act like radio button? thank you so much! Shall I remove the multiple attribute once RoleC is selected to accomplish that?

Comment: @GereltuyaBatdemberel .. Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/1ar5g43g/9/

Comment: it still requires to deselect the radio button to select the next one. Is it possible to make it like radio button where it can select the next one without having to deselect the previous one as in single selection mode? thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! It seems like If I select RoleC and then if I to select next one, it selects random radio buton. why is that?

Comment: after rolec is selected, and if I select roleA, it won't select all in rolea, it'd select random #5. it is not refreshing after rolec is selected.

Comment: you're the best!